# Optaplanner - Java heap out of space after big benchmarks

Tags: java, optaplanner

When running big benchmarks, most of the time after all of the solvers have finished i get a `java heap space out of memory` exception right after `Generating Benchmark report..` is printed. I increased the memory up to 4 GB, and still the error persists. Do i really need more memory, or is it something to do with the graphs that are generated. I should also note that the benchmarks that this happens to have 10 or more solvers.

Comment: Benchmarker generates aggregate reports at the end, so it needs potentially as much memory as all of the solver reports combined. You can try to run the benchmark aggregator (see the docs) and aggregate the report semi-manually.

Comment: **Which statistics have you enabled?** (show the part of your benchmark config xml) **How far does it get [in this method](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-benchmark/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/benchmark/impl/report/BenchmarkReport.java#L220)?** Once there's more information, please open a jira too, so we can track this.

Comment: I suspect that optaplanner-benchmark might not need to have all statistics in memory at the same time in the end, as it's also dumping them to CSV files.

Comment: First of all, sorry about the delayed reply on the comments.
Second, i am using all of the statistics enabled, even the deprecated ones(i believe there were multiple).
Third, i tried using the aggregator, and i guess it will do. I'm surprised i didn't know about it until now, since it's a really usefull thing.